# Get "this" from conditional?

Tags: jquery

In jquery, I want to performa an action for each element that returns true. I don't know how to reference the element from a conditional. This is what I tried before I realized I was doing it wrong:

```
if( $('input').val() ) {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in your question, you can use `each()`. `this` will refer to the DOM element that is currently being looped. (So you can use the `.value` property):

```
$('input').each(function(){
    var myVal = this.value 
    if(myVal){
        console.log(myVal);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('input')` will return a jQuery *set* of elements, which may have more than one in it. Calling `val` on a set only gives you the value of the *first* matched element.

You can check them individually with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if (this.value) { // No need for $(this).val() because `input` elements have a `value` property
        // do something with it
    }
});
```

Or you might want to get a set with just the matching elements in it, via [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
var inputsWithEmptyValues = $('input').filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
});
```

...and then do something with the set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()`. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('input').each(function(){ console.log($(this).val()) });
```

Comment: `this` within the `each` iterator callback doesn't have a `val()` method. And the OP was looking for `input` elements, not elements with an `"input"` class. And the question is about branching on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate like this:

```
$('#input').each(function (index, item) {
    Console.Log($(item).val());
});
```